# Can anyone recommend an open source number picker for ICS?

Tags: android, user-interface

I'm trying to implement a number picker for my Android app and I hate the ICS stock number picker:
[image: The one on the right]

Can anyone recommend a open source number picker that has a slot machine UI? Like the one in this application? https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sportstracklive.stopwatch&hl=en Like this:

[image: Slot machine style]

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

I recommend http://code.google.com/p/android-wheel/ . Used it a lot.

Also there are backport of stock ics, https://github.com/SimonVT/android-numberpicker and stock ics number picker has advantage for devices without touchscreen, but I do not know such devices :) so do not care.

Comment: I've been looking ages for a NumberPicker back port - thanks for sharing!